# Service Application is not appearing in SharePoint 2010 Central Administration

Tags: service-applications

In my farm, Some of the service applications are not displaying in the Service Applications List in

> CA-->Application Management-->Service Applications-->Manage service
>   applications

1. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail
2. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service
3. Web Analytics Data Processing Service

They do show up under Service Application list:

> CA-->System Settings-->Manage Server in this farm

but are not available on manage service applications list

where do i find these services and how do i configure them

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you was confused between **Service Application** and **Service** in SharePoint 2010

- Service Application (**CA** > **Application Management** > **Manage service applications**): it's hard to define what Service application is. However, Service application is responsible for separate capabilities on SharePoint 2010, such as **Managed Metadata Service application**(*Metadata, Content Type, ECM..*), **Search Service application**(*Search content, people*), User Profile Service application (*Social, Active Directory...*)
- Service (**CA** > **Application Management** > **Manage service on server**): Service is responsible for serving Service Application. For example, if you don't start **Managed Metadata Web Service**, you can't use **Managed Metadata Service application**, or If **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service** isn't started, you can't use multi-tenancy feature on SharePoint 2010. You just have two options for the services: **Start** and **Stop**.

The 3 services you mentioned in **Manage service on server**.

You can learn an overview of Service architecture as well as Service application here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc560988.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not all services implement the [Service Application Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536263.aspx) 
These services you mention are, as Andreas glaser explains on [his blog post](http://andreasglaser.net/post/2010/06/15/SharePoint-Foundation-2010-Service-Applications-and-Services-Incoming-Mail-Subscription-Settings-Workflow-Timer-Diagnostics-Outgoing-Mail-and-Usage.aspx), described as Configuration services that do net implement the SAF.

Comment: Hi @jorge. Welcome to our community. Please, instead of just pasting in a link, explain a bit about what you means answers the question *in* that link! Blogs tend to move around alot, so links tend to die faster than our community, so please help us persist the information in our site by adding more info to the benefit of all (including upvotes to gain reputation)